# grid finds font when run in console but not when rendering Rmd

Tags: r, graphics, r-markdown

When I run the chunk from the minimal Rmarkdown below in the console, the correct font is displayed. However, when I try to compile the Rmarkdown document to pdf I get the error: `font family 'Pacifico' not found in PostScript font database`. The font is available on my Ubuntu machine as `ttf` font. You can download the font at https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pacifico

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r fig.cap = "Plot with ttf font"}
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.text("Some text", gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Pacifico"))
```
````

It works when I use standard fonts like "Courier New"

Comment: [This issue and discussion](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/729) may be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error both with Rmarkdown and on the console when using the `pdf()` device:

```
library(grid)
pdf("...")
grid.newpage()
grid.text("Some text", gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Pacifico"))
# -> font family 'Pacifico' not found in PostScript font database
dev.off()
```

The easiest solution I have found is to use the `cairo_pdf()` device:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r fig.cap = "Plot with ttf font", dev = 'cairo_pdf'}
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.text("Some text", gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Pacifico"))
```
````

Alternatively you can use the `extrafont` package. You first have to call

```
extrafont::font_import()
```

in the console. After that you can use

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r fig.cap = "Plot with ttf font", dev = 'pdf'}
library(grid)
extrafont::loadfonts(quiet = TRUE)
grid.newpage()
grid.text("Some text", gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Pacifico"))
```
````