# grid.text() not rendering on PDF

Tags: r

Trying to understand why grid.text("Name") displays in my RStudio plots window but doesn't render on PDF output.

```
extrafont::loadfonts()
colors = c("#FFFFFF", "#232D69")
Logo = jpeg::readJPEG("picture.jpg", native=T)

# Layout
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
pdf(file="Test.pdf", width=10,height=10)
grid.newpage() #Create page
grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = colors[2], col = colors[2])) #Background color
grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = colors[1], col = colors[1]), x = unit(0, "npc"), y = unit(1, "npc"), width = unit(2, "npc"), height = unit(0.5, "npc"))
grid.raster(Logo, x = 0.1, y = 0.9, width = 0.15)
grid.text("Name", y = unit(0.90, "npc"), gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial", col = colors[2], cex = 3))
dev.off()
```

Comment: This could be helpful "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877885/grid-finds-font-when-run-in-console-but-not-when-rendering-rmd"

Comment: Thanks this was actually what I needed. I used the CairoPDF function instead of PDF and it works. If you want to answer my question, I'll accept it to give you credit for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to this link [grid finds font when run in console but not when rendering Rmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877885/grid-finds-font-when-run-in-console-but-not-when-rendering-rmd) using specific pdf function will solve the issue.